# Cookies across subdomains and server - PHP and Apache2

Tags: php, cookies, apache2, subdomain

I run a website which has many different subdomains. We are introducing a new download server which is using a subdomain of the main domain. The way we normally check user information is with cross subdomain cookies etc but I know this wont work because they of the different server and I wondered what would be the best way of checking if the user is logged in etc on the main server.

What I am wanting to do is the following

Sub1.domain.tld = main server

When you want to download a file, it will point you to the appropriate server where the files are stored

Sub2.domain.tld = download server

Is there any way to keep or check if the user was logged in please.

The way we normally do it with cookies accross subdomains is

```
setcookie('LoginVariable1', $LoginVariable1, $expiretime, '/', '.domain.tld');
setcookie('LoginVariable2', $LoginVariable2, $expiretime, '/', '.domain.tld');
```

Comment: The best way would be to share the session between the servers via database or memcache, for example.

Comment: Cookies shouldn't change between servers should they? Unless you mean the session cookie

Comment: Cookies are stored on the client so as long as they are defined for the top level domain, you should be able to access them. Of course, you're probably using a session UID that gets created dynamically by the main Server.  You could expose a service on the main server to check if the sessionID cookie is valid and call it from the download server.

Comment: I have just added the code which I use to set the cookies which works across different subdomains but not against servers.

Answer (score 0):

Cross domain cookies will exactly work in your case. The only case they would not work would be if you have "www.somedomain.example" and "download.someotherdomain.example", because you cannot define a cookie to be cross-domain for the top-level domain "example".

So this boils down to have a cookie that tells all servers something like the session id of the user, or an authentication token he got during login, and then all servers must ask some central authentication service whether this session or token is currently logged in.

Comment: When we set the cookies we do so to .domain.tld so that any subdomain can also use this however it doesnt seem to work when trying to read that cookie from another server

Comment: "doesnt seem to work" is no proper error analysis. What is the output of `var_dump($_COOKIE)`? Does it contain the cookie you set?

Answer (score 0):

If the subdomains map to different servers, you have two ways as I see it.

1) You can share the directory that php writes sessions to on server A and point server B there.

2) You can use database sessions and have both servers connect to a single database to verify/retrieve the session.

In both cases, you end up with a single, central place to store sessions.

Comment: Regarding point 1: php doesn't store cookies anywhere, the client does.

Comment: Note that you should not forget to implement proper session locking when using your own code - otherwise things will break.

Comment: @Maerlyn I said cookies and caught it quickly after. I meant the server side session file usually stored in a temp directory. If both servers shared that directory, then both servers theoretically could share sessions.

Comment: Sharing a filesystem between servers has it's own set of issues. I hope whatever network file system is chosen supports file locking...

Comment: @Sven My assumption would be that the download server wouldn't need to have anything but read access to the server session file to verify status and then you would be sent right back to the main server to continue on. Also, I'm not saying it is perfect, but it is an option and probably quicker to implement than database based sessions.